# Looking for an older (80s/90s) fantasy book series featuring intelligent dragons as antagonists

Tags: story-identification

The dragons in question could take on "human" forms that wore armor that was really their living scales shaped around their humanoid bodies. One notable story in the series is one dragon unleashing a wave of giant, furred creatures from dormancy who absorbed all energy, including heat, leaving behind a frozen wasteland wherever they went.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found out what series this was: the [Dragonrealm series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53041-dragonrealm) by Richard A Knaak.

> In Firedrake, a land ruled by the shape-shifting Dragon Kings, Cabe
> Bedlam is hunted for both the legacy he represents and the future he
> may bring. Yet, dragons may be the least of the dangers, for in a land
> drenched with sorcery, Cabe's very legacy may be what destroys him!
>
> [image]

Comment: Nice Larry Elmore cover art!